# Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

please help me to fix my problem in Spring MVC project. I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: **...**
```

My Project under github: [enter link description here](https://github.com/MaryGhazaryan/JobRepository)

Comment: I am afraid, we are gonna need some more info. You could paste your JobController class here, for instance

Comment: You often get long stacktraces when something goes wrong in Spring. Often, the ultimate cause is at the bottom of the stacktrace. Look for the error message there, which should give you a hint about what's wrong. From just this one line that you quoted above, it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are using @Autowired in JoinController to spring manage your JobService, when you use @Autowired in some class you need to put @Component or @Service in that class, so try to put in JobService some of these annotations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've checked my code and see that I've written @Service in my class. That's not the reason for the exception.